# How to convert a QString to ascii?

Tags: qt, c++11, ascii

I want to convert a `QString` to **ASCII**, but I don't know how.

I tried this:

```
QString("abcd").toAscii()
```

but this didn't work

Comment: Why are you tagging C++ _and_ QML? It seems you are only talking about C++

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting QString to Ascii value & Vice Versa in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772951/converting-qstring-to-ascii-value-vice-versa-in-qt)